# Document metadata usage on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, metadata

I have a requirement for documents available on SharePoint that the documents can be retrieved through metadata searches. Please can you advise how this would work practically.

For new documents how is the metadata set up, is this a manual exercise and if so how is this done